# Gamedev под android

Tags: android, разработка-игр

Посоветуйте хорошей (желательно, русскоязычной) литературы или интернет-ресурсов для обучения, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть книга Марио Цехнера "Программирование игр под Андроид" ([скачать](http://ad-file.com/59625008)).
Вот еще пару ссылок, по которым я учусь:
[1 тык](http://davidmd.ru/уроки-по-android/);
[2 тык](http://redgears.ru/основы-работы-с-графикой-android-часть-2/);
[3 тык](http://megadarja.blogspot.com/2009/03/android-1-surface.html);
[4 тык](http://dajver.blogspot.com/2012/01/android-5-2d.html);
[5 тык](http://dedfox.com/izuchaem-opengl-es2-pod-android-urok-1-samoe-nachalo/);